# Existence and Uniqueness Problem in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

$\textbf{Q:}$ Let $E$ be a non empty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $n\ge 1$ be an integer, and let $L<K$ be integers. Suppose that $\frac{L}{n}$ is a lower bound and $\frac{K}{n}$ is an upper bound of $E$. Then show that there is a unique $m$ such that $L<m\le K$ such that $\frac{m}{n}$ is upper bound for $E$, but $\frac{m-1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $E$.

It was asked in the exercise to solve this problem "without" using the Completeteness Property of $\mathbb{R}$, but I've used that property in my proof. Can anyone share a solution of the problem without using the sup property. Down below is my solution to the problem which I'm pretty sure is correct , but any suggestions regarding the proof writing syntax of the solution would be really appreciated.

$\textbf{Sol:}$   Let $P=\{\frac{L+i}{n}\}$ where $i=0,1,2,\cdots K-L$ be a partition of the closed interval $[\frac{L}{n},\frac{K}{n}]$. As $\frac{K}{n}$ is an upper bound for $E$, therefore $t:=\sup {E}$ exists. So, $\frac{L}{n}<t\le\frac{K}{n}$, therefore $t\in(\frac{L+i-1}{n},\frac{L}{n}]$ for some unique $i\in\{1,2,\cdots K-L\}$. Now construct $m=L+i$ which is unique as $i$ is unique, then clearly $L<m\le K$ and also $\frac{m-1}{n}<t\le\frac{m}{n}$. As $t$ is by definition the $\sup E$, therefore $\frac{m-1}{n}$ is not an upper bound for $E$ and $\frac{m}{n}$ is an upper bound for $E$. $\quad\blacksquare$

Comment: It seems impossible to find such a $m$ for $E = [0,2]$, $n=1$. In your proof, everything is okay up to "therefore $\frac{m-1}{n}$ is a lower bound for $E$",

Comment: My guess is that you can find $m$ so that $\frac{m-1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of $E$.

Comment: From what I remember, this comes up in the proof of the existence of a least upper bound for sets of real numbers that are bounded above. In that case, @ArcticChar would be right.  You need to find $M$ for which $m/n$ is an upper bound but $(m-1)/n$ is *not* (rather than $(m-1)/n$ being a lower bound for the set. I think the idea is that $L/n$ is *not* an upper bound but $K/n$ *is*, and so you can sort of find something in between them, which allows you to define a sequence whose limit is the supremum.

Comment: Whoops! I mistyped it, yes indeed, the problem was to prove the existence of such $m$ for which $(m-1)/n$ is not an upper bound rather than $(m-1)/n$ being a lower bound, I'm really sorry for that massive typo. Thanks all. Would my proof be correct in that case?

Comment: As I commented before, my understanding is that this lemma is used in the proof that a supremum exists, and so the fact that you're using the existence of a supremum is a problem. You need completeness to guarantee the existence of a supremum, after all.

Comment: No supremum is discussed in this result, @march they have just asking for an upper bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is correct and yes, completeness is an overkill in this case.

Following your proof, consider the set

$$ P_1 = \left\{ i\in \{0,1, \cdots, K-L\}: \frac{L+i}{n} \text{ is an upper bound of } E\right\}.$$

Note that $P_1$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$ and is non-empty since $K-L \in E$. Thus by the well-ordering principle, there is a least element $J \in P_1$. By construction, $\frac{L+J}{n}$ is an upper bound of $E$. However, $\frac{L+J-1}{n}$ is not. There are two cases:

(1) if $J = 0$, then $\frac{L}{n}$ is an upper bound of $E$. But since $\frac{L}{n}$ is also an upper bound of $E$, we must have $\{E\} = \{L/n\}$ and clearly $\frac{L-1}{n}$ is not an upper bound.

(2) if $J >0$, then $J-1 \ge 0$. Since $J-1\notin P_1$, $\frac{L+J-1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of $E$.

Now choose $m = L+J$ and this finishes the proof.